# Log4j concern on apache2 webserver

Tags: server, apache2, security, webserver

Given all the hype with the Log4j vulnerability I would like to know if my apache2 installation is vulnerable.  I searched for Log4j* files and only one came up:

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible_collections/community/windows/tests/integration/targets/win_xml/files/log4j.xml
```

Am I vulnerable?  This appears to be a version one and I'm thinking I can rename it?  Am I vulnerable?

---

This seems to be part of the distribution package for ansible_collections.  Looks like a file more for Windows hosts.  But I'd like to get a second opinion.

Comment: An update to fix it came out today: https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/focal/universe/security/apache-log4j2 My (boringly static) apache2 website didn't need the update.

Comment: Log4J is for Java, Apache2 is not Java.  You would need to be running some other service that is using Java, like Tomcat, or Jetty, etc.